# Making a show all out of Hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I am creating a directory of employees, and would like to let the user search for a specific employee. I want to have an option where it will show a full list of 'employees' when the user types `A`.

This is how my coding looks so far:

```
person = Hash.new()
person["John Doe"] = "Active"
person["Jane Doe"] = "Terminated"
person["Jimmy Doe"] = "Active"
person["Leslie Doe"] = "Terminated"
person.each do |key, value|
  puts "Enter the name of the employee, press 'A' for full list of employees."
  answer = gets.chomp!
  if value == "Terminated"
    puts "#{key} is a Terminated employee"
  elsif value == "Active"
    puts "#{key} is an Active employee"
  else
    puts "#{answer} is not an employee"
  end
end
```

It returns with `Enter employee name`, but it loops through and if it is not an employee, then it returns a full list such as:

```
Enter the name of the employee, press 'A' for full list of employees.
 John Doe
John Doe is an Active employee
Enter the name of the employee, press 'A' for full list of employees.
 active
Jane Doe is a Terminated employee
Enter the name of the employee, press 'A' for full list of employees.
 Jane Doe
Jimmy Doe is an Active employee
Enter the name of the employee, press 'A' for full list of employees.
 d
Leslie Doe is a Terminated employee
=> {"John Doe"=>"Active", "Jane Doe"=>"Terminated", "Jimmy Doe"=>"Active", "Leslie Doe"=>"Terminated"}
```

Why is my input disregarded, and how do I fix this? Would I have to define `A`?

Comment: As you can clearly observe, your input does not affect the program at all. It's simply discarded.

Comment: "why does it do the looping" - because you put a loop in there (`person.each do`)

Comment: obviously, but why is my input disregarded?

Comment: Well, because you don't use it in the code, of course.

Comment: This is a stupid ass question but, what are you talking about?

Comment: Read the code. You do `answer = gets.chomp`, but then you don't use that `answer` in conditions, etc.

Comment: It is returning the full hash `person` not because you typed `d` but because `each` returns the receiver. Whatever you type, it does not affect what the program prints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you have the `each` loop.

```
person = {
  "A" => "Full List",
  "John Doe" => "Active",
  "Jane Doe" => "Terminated",
  "Jimmy Doe" => "Active",
  "Leslie Doe" => "Terminated",
}
while true
  puts "Enter the name of the employee, press 'A' for full list of employees."
  answer = gets.chomp
  case person[answer]
  when "Full List"  then puts person.keys
  when "Terminated" then puts "#{answer} is a Terminated employee"
  when "Active"     then puts "#{answer} is an Active employee"
  else                   puts "#{answer} is not an employee"
  end
end
```

Comment: I have the each loop because I have no idea what I'm doing :)